Why don't I get full C++ stack traces in Firebase?
I've integrated Firebase into my Android game project and have successfully uploaded my libGame.so symbols to Firebase. I've also successfully generated crash reports, but when I look at the reports on Firebase Console it only shows the C++ module and line number where the crash occurred. It doesn't show all the C++ calls that lead up to the crash. How do I get Firebase to show the full stack trace?
Here's a screenshot of the stack trace. As you can see the call stack is only one level. None of the modules leading up to the crash module are shown.


Could you add more information? Like a screenshot or something?

Screenshot added.
